# MotionEvent ACTION_MOVE inaccurately generated on some devices

Tags: java, android, motionevent

I am using a simple function that intercepts and processes MotionEvents on a custom FrameLayout and interprets clicks. It works flawlessly on one device.
However, when I click on another device, it generates ACTION_MOVE events as long as my finger still touches the screen. I do not move it.
I wonder, why do the events created on 2 devices differ so much?

This is the code from my simple method

```
interceptTouchFrameLayout.setOnInterceptTouchEventListener(new InterceptTouchFrameLayout.OnInterceptTouchEventListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(InterceptTouchFrameLayout view, MotionEvent ev, boolean disallowIntercept) {
                switch (ev.getAction()) {
                    case 0:
                        dayRecyclerViewClickHandler = true;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        if(dayRecyclerViewClickHandler) {
                            dayRecyclerViewSetAdapter();
                            dayRecyclerViewClickHandler = false;
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        dayRecyclerViewClickHandler = false;
                }
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onTouchEvent(InterceptTouchFrameLayout view, MotionEvent event) {
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

In general it's a normal behavior to fire ACTION_MOVE events repeatedly even during still touches because of subtle noise arising in hardware level. Rather, the device which doesn't fire the events may have a slightly lower grade touch-device (with low accuracy, low resolution or less responsiveness).

You'd better adjust your code so that the app can work normally even if frequent extra ACTION_MOVE events (with nearly-zero movements) occur.